# How to paint correct text color in QStyledItemDelegate

Tags: qt, qt5, qstyle, qstyleditemdelegate

I'd like to draw a custom item delegate, which follows the current style. But there are differences between "WindowsVista/7" style and "WindowsClassic" for text color.

[image: difference between winViste/7 and winClassic]

Im using the following code for drawing the background (working):

```
void FriendItemDelegate::paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index) const
{
    painter->save();

    QStyleOptionViewItem opt = option;
    initStyleOption(&opt, index);
    QStyle *style = opt.widget ? opt.widget->style() : QApplication::style();
    QSize hint = sizeHint(opt, index);

    style->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_PanelItemViewItem, &opt, painter, opt.widget);
    ...
}
```

How to draw the text in correct color?

I can't use `style->drawControl(QStyle::CE_ItemViewItem, &opt, painter, opt.widget);` to draw the whole item, because I have to draw more special text than one text line. (This function would paint the colors correctly.)

I tried with `style->drawItemText(painter, opt.rect, opt.displayAlignment, opt.palette, true, "Hello World!");` but it paints always black. And for `painter->drawText()`, I have no idea how to set the correct pen color.

Comment: If you need to only color the text, you can avoid using item delegates and use `QAbstractItemModel::setData()` with `Qt::ForegroundRole`.

Comment: I don't want to draw text with a specific text color. I want to draw text with the text color of the current style.

Comment: Current style of what? Show your QSS.

Comment: I have no QSS. I just want to paint the text of the selected item BLACK for "Windows Vista/7" themes and WHITE for "Windows classic" themes, like the image in the question. (Of cause, it should work for all other OS to...)

Answer (score 4):

The [doc](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstyle.html#drawItemText) for `QStyle::drawItemText` says:

> If an explicit textRole is specified, the text is drawn using the
>   palette's color for the given role.

You can use it like this inside your delegate `paintEvent`:

```
QString myText = ...;

QPalette::ColorRole textRole = QPalette::NoRole;
if (option.state & QStyle::State_Selected)
{
    textRole = QPalette::HighlightedText;
}

qApp->style()->drawItemText(painter, opt.rect, opt.displayAlignment, 
                            opt.palette, true, myText, textRole);
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
if (option.state & QStyle::State_Selected && 
    option.state & QStyle::State_Active)
    painter->setPen(option.palette.color(QPalette::HighlightedText));
else 
    painter->setPen(option.palette.color(QPalette::Text));

painter->drawText(textRect, title, textOption);
```